# How to see the value of Variables in Xdebug window of Sublimetext 3

Tags: php, sublimetext3, xdebug

I am trying to debug using PHP extension PHP Xdebug. But I want to know what these below variable hold after setting the break points.

[image]

When I double click on this variable it does not show any valuable data (as shown in below image).

[image]

I want to know if is there any way to see value stored in every variable?

Comment: can you please replace the images with codeblocks.

Comment: used `debug_backtrace()` function for debugging